# Why is my navbar covered by the dropdown navigation menu?

Tags: html, css, navbar, mediaquery

When using media query to ensure proper layout for screens smaller than 800 pixels, the navbar dropdown covers the navbar itself, meaning the menu toggle button is unclickable as it is hidden by the dropdown navbar menu.

This is what it looks like
[image: This is what it looks like]

This is what I need it to look like

[image: This is what I need it to look like]

```js
var MenuItems = document.getElementByID("MenuItems");

MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";

function menutoggle(){
  if(MenuItems.style.maxHeight == "0px") {
    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "200px";
  }
  else {
    MenuItems.style.maxHeight = "0px";
  }
}
```

```css
.MenuIcon {
  width: 28px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: none;                             
}


/*------------Media query for menu-------------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    left: 0;
    background: #333;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.4444s;
  }

  nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    color: #fff;
  }

  .MenuIcon {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="Header">
  <div class="Container">
    <div class="Navbar">
        <div class="Logo">
            <img src="Images/JDSTUDIOSLOGO.png" width="125px">
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul id="MenuItems">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Content</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <img src="Images/Cart16.png" width="30px" height="30px";>
        <img src="Images/MENU3.png" class="MenuIcon" onclick="menutoggle()">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try using padding instead of margin in "nav ul li". For example.

nav ul li
{
    display: block;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

Comment: Without a working reproducible example to see what all is going on, I'm going to guess that it has to do with `top: 70px`. Maybe try `bottom: 0`. BTW, the HTML attributes `width` and `height` (in your `img` tag) require only numerical values without a unit.

Comment: You could try setting a `z-index` gt 1 for the menu

Comment: You don't have styling when the media is smaller than 800px